VB.NET: optimize function to return a new byte array that does not contain ‘3’ bytes, and number of skipped bytes
I have written a VB.NET function that takes a byte array, a starting position, and a number of bits as input. The goal is to remove any occurrences of 3 from the specified range being searched. The function should return the new byte array with the specified length and the information about how many bytes were skipped.
Example: Given the byte array {103, 100, 0, 51, 172, 217, 0, 113, 1, 83, 229, 188, 4, 64, 0, 0, 3, 0, 64, 0, 0, 15, 3, 198, 12, 101, 128}, the starting position (in bits) is 106, and the number of bits is 32. The function should then return {64, 0, 0, 0, 64} (note the skipped 3) and a value of 1. There are 40 bits here, instead of the 32 specified, because the last byte has already started or because the starting position in bits was not aligned to bit position 0. The function should also return the number of skipped bytes so that I can update the position in the bitstream accordingly.
Edge case: If the last read byte is a 3, and it is partially read, it should not be skipped.
The original byte array must not be modified.
I quickly wrote the function a while ago, and it works. However, I am posting this on CodeReview to get suggestions to increase the cpu performance.
The use case is parsing specific items in H.264. Occasionally, there are threes between zero-bytes so that the decoder does not confuse the zero-bytes with a new frame (to put it simply).
I created a test project for you:
Option Strict On
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Friend NotInheritable Class FormMain
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim byteArray As Byte() = New List(Of Byte)() From {103, 100, 0, 51, 172, 217, 0, 113, 1, 83, 229, 188, 4, 64, 0, 0, 3, 0, 64, 0, 0, 15, 3, 198, 12, 101, 128}.ToArray()
        Dim result As (Byte(), Integer) = ExtractRelevantBytesWithout3(byteArray, 106, 32)
    End Sub

    Private Shared Function ExtractRelevantBytesWithout3(byteArray As Byte(), bitStartPosition As Integer, bitCount As Integer) As (Byte(), numberOfSkippedBytes As Integer)
        Dim result As New List(Of Byte)()

        Dim bitsRemaining As Integer = bitCount
        Dim currentBitPosition As Integer = bitStartPosition
        Dim numberOfSkippedBytes As Integer = 0
        Dim increaseOnce As Boolean = True

        While bitsRemaining > 0 AndAlso currentBitPosition \ 8 < byteArray.Length
            Dim currentByteIndex As Integer = currentBitPosition \ 8
            Dim bitIndexWithinByte As Integer = currentBitPosition Mod 8
            If bitIndexWithinByte > 0 AndAlso increaseOnce Then
                bitsRemaining += 8
                increaseOnce = False
            End If

            Dim currentByte As Byte = byteArray(currentByteIndex)

            If currentByte = CByte(3) AndAlso bitsRemaining > 8 Then ' bitsRemaining > 8 means: Do not skip if the 3 is not read completely.
                currentBitPosition += 8 ' Skip to the next byte
                numberOfSkippedBytes += 1
                Continue While
            End If

            result.Add(currentByte)
            currentBitPosition += 8
            bitsRemaining -= Math.Min(bitsRemaining, 8) ' Deduct processed bits
        End While

        Return (result.ToArray(), numberOfSkippedBytes)
    End Function

End Class

